# Pygame - Printing out seconds using Time

Tags: python, time, pygame, clock

this may be something simple, yet I can't figure out a way to do this; I am trying to print the seconds. I use:

```
r = int(pygame.time.get_ticks)
print(r/1000)
```

It prints out the seconds but what I want it to do is to print out the seconds just once. So basically it would output something like: 11111112222222233333333..., when I am looking for something like: 1 2 3...
If anyone can help me out, Id really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't really have nothing to do with pygame, specifically. Use a variable which is outside your main loop called, for example, 't' and assign it to 0. Then, check if get_ticks (converted to an integer) is different from t, if it is - print the get_ticks and assign the value to t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to track the last value for seconds, and only print if the new value for seconds changes.

```
last_seconds = None
while True:
    # Run game
    r = int(pygame.time.get_ticks)
    seconds = r / 1000
    if seconds != last_seconds:
        print(seconds)
        last_seconds = seconds
```

Comment: I'm attempting to use your example but I am not getting the seconds, I am getting decimal numbers. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a closure by writing a function that captures the "last ticks" and compares this with the "current ticks". This way you only print the "time since init" every 1s.

**Example:**

```
def get_time_since_init():
    last_ticks = int(pygame.time.get_ticks())
    def wrapper()
        ticks = int(pygame.time.get_ticks())
        delta = (ticks - last_ticks) / 1000
        if delta > 1:
            last_ticks = ticks
            print(ticks / 1000)
    return wrapper
```